# Esperar ou verificar append

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma `div` que deve fazer um `append` de alguns elementos e, após isso, deve fazer um *scroll* até o final dela.

O problema é que o *scroll* é executado antes do append ser finalizado. O código (genérico) está assim:

```
$("div").append(output);
$("div").prop("scrollTop", $("div").prop("scrollHeight"));
```

Se eu colocar o segundo comando dentro de um `setTimeout`, isso tudo funciona, mas as vezes o tempo de append pode variar e acabar sendo maior do que o tempo que defini no `setTimeout` e de novo não vai executar o segundo comando.

O que acontece é que, como o primeiro comando não foi completo, o segundo não tem conteúdo para dar *scroll*, pois os comandos vão seguindo, sem terem necessariamente terminado.

O que eu preciso é de algum tipo de verificação que observa se o `append` foi finalizado, ou algo assim, para o código poder continuar. E a função com esses comandos só é chamada uma vez.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descobri um modo de fazer a verificação de `append` para uma `div` que usa `overflow`, abaixo:

```
var intervalo = setInterval(function() {
    // Quando achar algo dentro da div
    if ($("div").children().length > 0) {
        // No meu caso, gostaria que o scroll rolasse até o final
        $("div").prop("scrollTop", $("div").prop("scrollHeight"));
        // Cancela o setInterval
        clearInterval(intervalo);
    }
}, 1);
```

Pode-se colocar outro valor ao invés de 1 para o intervalo. Quando ele verificar que houve o aumento de tamanho do `scroll` ele para a verificação e o código continua.

Answer (score 3):

Infelizmente o método `append()` não tem um callback p/ verificar se foi feito ou não, logo surgem as alternativas de usar `setTimeout`, mas como no seu caso tu disse que pode variar muito, tenta usar a função `animate` da seguinte forma:

```js
$('#append').click(function() {

  $('#divUm').append('<div style="height:800px; border:2px solid red;"></div>');

  $('#divUm').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#divUm').prop("scrollHeight")
  }, 1500);

});
```

```css
#divUm {
  height: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="append">append</button>
<div id="divUm">divUm</div>
```

Comment: Infelizmente esse modo não funcionou. Inclusive, eu já havia tentado, sem sucesso.

Comment: @MarlonLuís se tiver como postar mais detalhes, a div e o conteúdo do append, pode ser no jsfiddle.net, vamos atrás da solução.

Comment: Tudo bem, @Mathias, consegui resolver o problema e postei o resultado abaixo.

Comment: @MarlonLuís Maravilha, que bom que conseguiu responder, espero que a minha resposta seja mais útil em uma próxima vez, até cogitei em sugerir o setInterval mas achei meio perigoso, enfim que bom que funcionou.